# Null Pointer Exception on StringTokenizer - Android

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null

Can someone tell me why do I get Null Pointer Exception error in this part of my code? Especially this line---- StringTokenizer wholeresp = new StringTokenizer(modGen.response,"|");

```
public void run() {



                                modGen = new ClaimVoucherActivity();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ClaimVoucherActivity.this,ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("customerID", customerID);
                            intent.putExtra("type", type);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("email", email);
                            intent.putExtra("voucher", voucher);
                            intent.putExtra("branch", branch);
                            intent.putExtra("issued", issued);
                            intent.putExtra("expiration", expiration);
                            intent.putExtra("status", status);
                            intent.putExtra("vouchername", vouchername);
                            intent.putExtra("employeeid", employeeid);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }   }
                );
```

Comment: If you got an NPE on that line, modGen is null

Comment: This **modGen** will be null.

Comment: If **modGen** is any class object ? Have you initialized it??

Comment: yes @PiyushGupta its a class with string values.

Comment: So have you initialized it?

Comment: Yes I have  public static String response; inside modGen class

Comment: can you post initialize line on your code, where you call `modGen = new YourClassName();`?

Comment: should I put that? where? at the modgen class?

Comment: before using that, top of `StringTokenizer wholeresp = new StringTokenizer(modGen.response,"|");`

Comment: Its already there look at my code.

Comment: i don't see that line, just add `modGen = new YourClassName();` to first line of your method

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes I have public static String response; inside modGen class

Comment: its error :( @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: Cannot be resolve variable @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: what? can you post your code with change

Comment: what is type of `modGen`? you initialize `modGen` with your activity class, you need initialize that with your class of  `modGen`

Comment: modgen is a class where the strings are.

Comment: can you post `modgen` class?

Comment: I already initialized is. It stil null pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i see your code you initialize `modgen` with your activity class that is not true. you must use following code:

```
public void run() {
          modGen = new ModGenClassName();
          StringTokenizer wholeresp = new StringTokenizer(modGen.response,"|");
          Intent intent = new Intent(ClaimVoucherActivity.this,ClaimVoucherDetailsActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("customerID", customerID);
          intent.putExtra("type", type);
          intent.putExtra("name", name);
          intent.putExtra("email", email);
          intent.putExtra("voucher", voucher);
          intent.putExtra("branch", branch);
          intent.putExtra("issued", issued);
          intent.putExtra("expiration", expiration);
          intent.putExtra("status", status);
          intent.putExtra("vouchername", vouchername);
          intent.putExtra("employeeid", employeeid);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);

          }   
        });
```

i don't know ClassName of ModGen, you need replace your class name with `ModGenClassName`

this is not good way to send 10 item separately with your intent, i think you can handle all item with maximum two class, then send object of those too next activity, this is much better  and cleaner way.

Comment: this is right. But now I get NumberFormatException error at this line    spinEmployee.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(employ)-1);. At the next activity where I pass this codes.

Comment: what is the employ value? check that,

Comment: @jajaja if one answer help you and make your problem solve you must tick that as answer to help other people.